# Getting OAuth2 Client Secret inside App Engine application in a secure way

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an application in Google App Engine which uses OAuth2.
I work under the assumption that the OAuth ClientID is a public and exposed data because it is used in the URL the client is sent to authenticate.

I need a way to access the Client Secret because I don't want to just hard-code it into my code.

Is there a way to access the Credentials data using my App Engine Service Account?

If not what is a good way to store the Client Secret in a secure way?

Answer (score 0):

Google recently released new service to storing secrets https://cloud.google.com/kms/

You can use this service to securely manage any secrets (including access key and secrets rotation, invalidation ...). Consider following strategies whey you need to manage your secrets (sourced from https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/secret-management):

> Choosing a secret management solution
>
> Choosing the best secret management solution depends on your unique
>   existing environment, secrets, and security needs. Some common
>   approaches include:
>
> 1. Storing secrets in code, encrypted with a key from Cloud KMS. This
>      solution is typically implemented by encrypting secrets at the
>      application layer. Using this solution helps provide an additional
>      layer of protection against insider threats by limiting the scope of
>      access to the secret. Access to the secret is restricted from all
>      developers with access to the code to only those who have both access
>      to the code and the corresponding key. Even in cases where all
>      developers have access to both the code and the key, implementing this
>      option has benefits as it provides the ability to audit access to the
>      secret, which might not be possible in a code repository.
> 2. Storing secrets in a storage bucket in Cloud Storage, encrypted at
>      rest. This solution has similar benefits as the previous solution, in
>      that it limits access to secrets to a smaller set of developers and
>      provides the ability to audit that access. In addition, by storing
>      secrets in a separate location, you can more easily rotate secrets
>      when necessary; for example, if a security breach is detected. Also,
>      this solution allows for separation of systems; if the code repository
>      using the secrets is breached, the secrets themselves might still be
>      protected.
> 3. Using a third-party secret management solution. A dedicated secret
>      management tool builds on the first two options in this list. In
>      addition, these tools might allow you to not only rotate secrets more
>      easily, but, in some cases, either perform that rotation on your
>      behalf or simplify regular rotation.
>
> Warning: Another common option is to store your secrets directly in
>   code. This option is not recommended. Although this is the simplest
>   solution to implement, it potentially allows anyone with access to
>   your code to also have access to your secrets, leaving you vulnerable
>   to attacks from inside and outside your organization. This
>   vulnerability could, at best, lead to abuse of your data and accounts
>   elsewhere; at worst, it could potentially expose even more data to the
>   attacker.